# First and Follow Algorithm in Compiler Design

Tags: compiler

While I was studying Compilers,I saw an example in [first and follow](http://1drv.ms/1xV0ve4) that illustrated how to 'find the first and follow' non-terminals in a grammer.

But I couldn't get how `FOLLOW(E')=FOLLOW(E)={ $ ,) }` even though the first and follow algorithm states it like that.

I don't understand why the FOLLOW(E') contains ')'.  Does anyone know how this works?

Comment: F -> (E) -> (T E')

And that's how you get an `E'` followed by a `)` .

Comment: @KilianFoth:that's very right.Could you explain how the 3rd statement came in first and follow algorithm because I couldn't get how Follow(A) woud reside in Follow(B).If there is a production $A\toB$ how would Follow(A) reside in Follow(B) if B comes only after A.I think only A's follow would be B(First(B)).But follow of B would be only which comes after B.But I can't see A coming after B.Could you help me.

Comment: You're confused by two different uses of 'after'. One concerns *order of symbols in a string*. The other concerns *sequence of transformations in time*. (And it doesn't help that the *temporal* sense is itself expressed as *symbol order* when dealing with production rules.) Try substituting every use of 'after' with 'to the right of' or 'in the next step' in the material to make it less confusing.

Comment: @KilianFoth:sorry.I have mistyped the comment.Could you explain how the 3rd statement came in first and follow algorithm because I couldn't get how Follow(A) woud reside in Follow(B).If there is a production $A\toB$ how would Follow(A) reside in Follow(B) if B comes right of A.I think only A's follow would be B(First(B)).But I think follow of B would be only the non-terminals which comes right of B.But I can't see A to the right of B.

Comment: `AB` is completely different from `A -> B`. One is a string, the other is a *production rule*. And the production rule doesn't state that A comes to the left of B, it says "if you have A you can *replace* it with B". That's why everything that can follow an `A` can also follow `B`, because every A might be replaced by a `B` at will.

Comment: @KilianFoth:thanks for your answer.I was really confused with the two notions which you mentioned.But now it's gone.Could you also tell why does a $ comes only for follow of start symbol.Can it come also for another non terminal if that(NT) has nothing to right of it,but it's not a start symbol.

Comment: It doesn't. In a further slide you see that FOLLOW(T) also contains $. (No matter what string the start symbols, the rightmost element can *always* be followed by $, since, well, it's the rightmost one.)

Comment: @KilianFoth:oh that's right.Can they be more than one start symbol in a grammer.

Comment: @justin: No, you should have only one start symbol. If you land in a situation where you think you need two (or more) start symbols `S1` and `S2`, you should add an additional production `S -> S1 | S2` to get a singular start symbol.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau:Thanks for your anwser.Could you tell me whether A -> BC means we should replace `A` with `B `or `C` or whether it means we should first take `B` then `C` while considering production `A`.

Comment: The notation `A -> BC` means that an `A` produces a `B` followed by a `C`.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau:I would also like to know whether NFA is only used for conversion of (regular expressions to NFA and then to DFA).Is it possible to realize NFA practically. Or whether NFA is used beacuse it is efficient than DFA.Could you tell me whether I have to ask this as a seperate question.

Comment: That looks like something that deserves its own question.